# Two ways of getting balance in Solidity

Tags: solidity

As far as I know there are 2 ways of getting balance of a certain address.

1. `address firstAddress;
   "firstAddress.balance"`
   This will get the balance of the address "firstAddress".
2. `address firstAddress;
   mapping ( address => uint) balanceFirstAddress;
   balanceFirstAddress[firstAddress]`
   This will get the balance of the address "firstAddress".

I understand the first one is just go to an address and get its balance. I don't get how come `mapping(address => uint)` will get the balance of that address. Isn't it `mapping` just a hashing function that hash the function from hex to some binary value that can do mathematical manipulation?

Additionally, if both function gets the balance of the address, what is the difference between them and when should I use which?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8):

I think it's important to note that by default `mapping (address => uint256) balanceFirstAddress` doesn't return a balance of the address. You have to initialize that mapping to have a balance first, and then add to it when appropriate. If you don't map a value to a key, it'll just return zero.

**What is a mapping?**

Mappings are used to structure value types and consists of a `_KeyType` linked to a `_ValueType`.

It's declared like so `mapping(_KeyType => _ValueType) mappingName;`

For example: `mapping (address => uint256) balanceOf;`

The `address` is the `_KeyType` and the `uint256` is the `_ValueType`. The `uint256` in this case represents the balance linked to an `address`.

You can think of the `address` as the key you'll pass through to return a `uint256` value .

`uint256 balance = balanceOf[address]; /// balance would be a uint256 value.`

According [to the documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html#mappings), mappings are empty by default and must have a new `_keyType` mapped to a `_ValueType`.

So to add a balance to an address you would type:

```
uint256 balanceToAdd = 200;

balanceOf[address] += balanceToAdd;
/// balanceOf[address] is 200 (address = 200)
```

**Which one should you use?**

It depends on what you're trying to achieve, if you just want the overall ether balance of an address, you can use `address.balance`. If your contract wants to track the sending and receiving of a ERC20 token, you would map the increase and decrease of that token balance to an address.

Here's an example:

```
contract MyToken {
    /* This creates an array with all balances */
    mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;

    /* Initializes contract with initial supply tokens to the creator of the contract */
    function MyToken(
        uint256 initialSupply
        ) {
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = initialSupply;              // Give the creator all initial tokens
    }

    /* Send coins */
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) {
        require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= _value);           // Check if the sender has enough
        require(balanceOf[_to] + _value >= balanceOf[_to]); // Check for overflows
        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;                    // Subtract from the sender
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;                           // Add the same to the recipient
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, sir! It is a great explanation. Really appreciate your time and input! The only thing I am still confused about is this: when you said "If your contract wants to track the sending and receiving of a ERC20 token, you would map the increase and decrease of that token balance to an address.", why you wanna use mapping instead of "msg.balance += _value"?  I didn't understand how your example demonstrated that.

Comment: `address.balance` is a global variable that returns the balance of the address in wei (smallest unit of ether). You can't perform operations like addition and subtraction on `address.balance`. You can however transfer/send ether to an address, which would increase/decrease the `address.balance` [See docs](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/units-and-global-variables.html#address-related)

Comment: To help clarify, an address (doesn't matter if the address is an account or a contract) can hold ether and is accessible via `address.balance`. This is built into how Ethereum works by default. Usually, an internal mapping in a contract is used to track if a contract's balance should be divided up among other address and eventually transferred out. A token contract is similar to this except the state dictates token ownership and `this.balance` still refers to the ether balance and not token supply.

Comment: @ShaunBevan Thank you. I thought you could do addition and subtraction with `address.balance`. I think that was what confused me.

Comment: Just to complete @AdamKipnis 's explanation, ether is the native token in Ethereum. Although you write `ether`, you are referring to the corresponding native token for a given blockchain. For example, matic in the case of Polygon and BNB in the case of *Binance Smart Chain*

Answer (score 2):

Prior to version 0.5.0, Solidity allowed address members to be accessed by a contract instance, for example this.balance. This is now forbidden and an explicit conversion to address must be done: address(this).balance.